# Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :secondAppModule

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-activity, module

i have an application that needs to be able to "revert" back to an older stated version if the user doesn't have the required hardware, so i have the new Application as App module in the project and the older secondAppModule as another module in the same project

I'm trying to start the secondAppModule via an intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, HomeActivity_old.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
```

and have added it as a dependency into the `build.gradle`(Module: App)

```
implementation project(':secondAppModule')
```

but am running into these errors that i can't get rid of

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':App@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :secondAppModule.
Open File
Show Details
```

Any ideas why this error wont go away? Thanks

Comment: check your `settings.gradle` to ensure that you have `:secondAppModule` inside. e.g. `include ':app', ':secondAppModule'
`

Comment: Was already included

include ':App', ':secondAppModule '

project(':secondAppModule ').projectDir = new File('App/libs/secondAppModule ')

Comment: Oops, try to check you relative path is correct

Comment: Adding the dependency automatically via Android Studio, I believe it has something to do with add ons being incompatible

Comment: Posting your build.gradle files will be helpful with solving your problem